# How can I install Dieharder in Cygwin on Windows 10?

Tags: automated-tests, cygwin

I am trying to install Dieharder in Cygwin and I am unable to do it. Can someone please help?

I have tried it install Gentoo, which doesn't work. There was an issue with the installation.  I have tried to apt-cyg the dieharder package. That didn't work either because it couldn't find the package.

I want to run the dieharder tests on my own random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

Download the `https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder/dieharder-3.31.1.tgz` file. See README and INSTALL files. From README:

> You MUST run ./autogen.sh FIRST.  Then ./configure, make and so on
>   should work.  Sorry, if I distribute it any other way some aspect of the
>   Gnu Build Tools breaks for some system.  See INSTALL for more details.

I ran `./configure --prefix=$(HOME)/local` so I would have a non-root install (See instructions following:

> ./configure --prefix=$(HOME)/usr

and modify as you wish.)

At this point, I get an error about version mismatch in `./libtool`, which is a generated file. I think the error may relate to `./autogen.sh` using `autoreconfig` instead of doing all the things commented out in that script. Comment out the autoreconfig and uncomment the lines above.

Apply this patch to `./include/dieharder/libdieharder.h`:

```
*** libdieharder.h.ORIGINAL     2011-10-14 07:41:37.000000000 -0600
--- libdieharder.h      2019-07-20 20:41:14.658335100 -0600
***************
*** 23,29 ****
--- 23,33 ----

  /* This turns on M_PI in math.h */
  #define __USE_BSD 1
+ #undef __BSD_VISIBLE
+ #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
  #include <math.h>
+ #undef __BSD_VISIBLE
+ #define __BSD_VISIBLE 0
  #include <limits.h>
  #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
  #include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
***************
*** 298,300 ****
--- 302,305 ----
    double c[RGB_MINIMUM_DISTANCE_MAXDIM];
  } dTuple;

+ typedef       unsigned int    uint;           /* from /usr/include/sys/types.h */
```

Now running `make` should compile (with warnings). I have not tested other than running with no args and with -l.